# How to set "native" db types when passing parameters, e.g., NpgsqlDbType / SqlDbType / or just parameter.TypeName / etc.)

Tags: .net, sql-server, postgresql, sqlite, dapper

I'm trying to figure out a way to set "native" db type, such as:

- PostgreSQL: [NpgsqlDbType](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/api/NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.html)
- SQL Server: [SqlDbType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqldbtype)
- SQLite: [SqliteType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlite.sqlitetype)
- and others

when using [DynamicParameters](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper/blob/main/Dapper/DynamicParameters.cs).

without writing a lot of boilerplate code, I can only see two method overloads, namely:

```cs
public void Add(string name, object? value, DbType? dbType, ParameterDirection? direction, int? size)
{...}

public void Add(string name, object? value = null, DbType? dbType = null, ParameterDirection? direction = null, int? size = null, byte? precision = null, byte? scale = null)
{...}
```

They obviously only support `DbType`, and while I've found some workaround in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54057677/4636721), it looks really tedious just to change the type, I thought there would have been some option to pass the native db type name directly as a workaround, but this option is not available either.